# ksoap: unable to casting data recovered from webservice

Tags: android, parsing, android-ksoap2

I have a service that return a List of strings, and i need to invoke it from android client, but something gone wrong. In fact, sometimes i obtain a cast exception and my app crash. This is the code for recover data:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "vector<soapobject>",
                    new Vector<SoapObject>().getClass());

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Vector<SoapObject> result = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();

            return result;
```

and the error is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
```

on line where i cast envelope.getResponse(). what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=24

check out the link

Or

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                        URL);

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                        .bodyIn;
                webResponse = response.toString();
```

Comment: your first two code snippet doesn't work too, i obtain always that exception. The second code snippet isn't good for my use case, because my service is declared for return List<String[]> and not primitive types

Comment: I can't still find a solution for my problem